# Possible application of Mittag-Leffler's Expansion Theorem for a function with a double pole like $\csc(z^2)$

Tags: calculus, mittag-leffler-function

I have a doubt. In order to apply the theorem you have to meet the conditions : $f$ must be a meromorphic function that has only simple poles, is continuous, or has a removable singularity at 0.

I have tried to calculate the expansion at two points $0$ and $\pi$ of $\csc(z^2)$ which has double poles whereas if you see the following representation, both developments seem valid.

$$\sum _{k=2}^{\infty } \frac{2 e^{-i \pi  k} x^2 \left(x^2+\pi \right)}{\pi  \left(k^2-1\right) \left(\pi ^2 k^2-x^4\right)}-\sum _{k=2}^{\infty } \frac{2 e^{-i \pi  k} x^4 \left(x^2+\pi \right)}{\pi ^2 \left(k^2-1\right) \left(\pi ^2 k^2-x^4\right)}-\frac{x^2}{2 \pi ^2}+\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{2 x^2}{\pi ^2-x^4}=\csc \left(x^2\right)$$
$$-\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{\pi  (-1)^{-k}}{(\pi -k) \left(\pi  k-x^2\right)}+\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{-k} x^2}{\pi  (\pi -k) \left(\pi  k-x^2\right)}+\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{\pi ^2}+\csc \left(\pi ^2\right)=\csc \left(x^2\right)$$
[image]
I have calculated a new expansion around -Pi, Pi (thanks to the comments of @Jean Marie)and the almost perfect approximation can be seen graphically using the double poles of the function it seems that Mittag leffler's theorem can be extended to functions with double poles,although I have not been able to prove equality itself

of course you can always calculate the expansion of two points around -Pi,Pi of Csc(x) and change x by x^2, and this if equality can be proved, (well I don't know if these developments have been done before , but they do not seem to have much application in mathematics due to the interest they arouse)
$$\sum _{k=2}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{-k} \left(\pi -x^2\right) \left(x^2+\pi \right)}{\pi ^2 (k-1) (k+1) \left(\pi  k-x^2\right)}-\sum _{k=2}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{-k} \left(\pi -x^2\right) \left(x^2+\pi \right)}{\pi ^2 (k-1) (k+1) \left(\pi  k+x^2\right)}+\frac{\left(3 \pi -x^2\right) \left(x^2+\pi \right)}{4 \pi ^2 \left(\pi -x^2\right)}-\frac{\left(x^2-\pi \right) \left(x^2+\pi \right)}{\pi ^2 x^2}-\frac{\left(\pi -x^2\right) \left(x^2+3 \pi \right)}{4 \pi ^2 \left(x^2+\pi \right)}=\csc \left(x^2\right)$$

Comment: Why do you say they are identical ? The graphical representations (that you have pushed far enough with a hundred terms) should be superimposed. A remark: $\csc(z^2)$ could be qualified as a "not-very-natural function" (the argument increases very quickly!). Are you sure you didn't want to address $\csc(z)^2$ ?

Comment: Besides, your expressions are too tiny.

Comment: @Jean Marie , using only 100 term for  reasons of computational simplicity but$$\sum _{k=2}^{\infty } \frac{2 e^{-i \pi  k} x^2 \left(x^2+\pi \right)}{\pi  \left(k^2-1\right) \left(\pi ^2 k^2-x^4\right)}-\sum _{k=2}^{\infty } \frac{2 e^{-i \pi  k} x^4 \left(x^2+\pi \right)}{\pi ^2 \left(k^2-1\right) \left(\pi ^2 k^2-x^4\right)}-\frac{x^2}{2 \pi ^2}+\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{2 x^2}{\pi ^2-x^4}=\csc \left(x^2\right)$$

Comment: You should copy this expression into your question.

Comment: I have thought it is important to edit your question (I wish you agree to the changes). While doing this editing, I began to understand your issue in a better way : for example, there is a *perfect matching* of the three curves on the last interval $(\sqrt{\pi},\sqrt{2\pi})$. Right ? Is it the same on the next intervals (not displayed). But why this matching doesn't take place in the first two intervals ?